# Saving and comparing values in a for loop Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops

So I have a list of 16 variables. For each variable, I do some calculations for instance

```
for i = 1:16

 calcu = aa + cc

end
```

calcu has several lines but out of the 16 variables, I want to save intermediate values of only 11 specific variables, for ex, only for variables stored in chosen_variable.

```
chosen_variable = ({'A','B',......,'N'})
```

I have to compare values of variable A with the 10 remaining variables

```
for n = 1 : no of lines
    If calcu_A(n)>calcu_B(n) then
    New_Calcu(n) = calcu_A(n)
    Else 
    New_Calcu(n) = calcu_B(n)
end
end

for n = 1 : no of lines
    If calcu_A>calcu_C(n) then
    New_Calcu(n) = calcu_A(n)
    Else 
    New_Calcu(n) = calcu_C(n)
end
end
```

and so on ..

But I can't seem to figure out how to do so. Could you please help ?